# Hey! i could not found How to make it correct?

Tags: string, pointers

I could not found How to make it correct - please help.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
main(void)
{       
    char *string="Hello!World";  
    while(string){       
        putchar(string); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
# include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char *string = "Hello!World";

    while (*string) {
        putchar(*string++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Little reminder: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, if the answer is good for you :)